# Connect SearchBox with ListBox in VCL

Tags: delphi, listbox, pascal, vcl

Hi Guys I have a SearchBox and a ListBox holding some Items.

I know that, in FMX if you create a ListBox you can right-click on it and automatically add a searchbox that works out of the box.

I would like to have the same behavior in VCL so if I type a letter I get displayed everything holding the letter or the entered string.

How would you connect the SearchBox to the ListBox? And how would a search function look like or can it be generated automatically like in FXM just by linking it ?

Comment: I did this for a `TListView` control some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074210/282848. The basic principle works for `TListBox` -- the only difference is that it is simpler with a `TListBox`.

Comment: Looks like a lot of code so I guess you cant get the FMX behavior out of the box? Ty I will check the code!

Comment: @yeslamFaded: True. You won't get it for free.