# Performing search in separate thread delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm trying to make a search which runs on a separate thread and updates listview with matched items using Synchronize.

previously when  search was working on main thread. i was using onchange event of TButtonedEdit. to detect the string that user wish to search for. & perform search on listview items.

I want to know how to detect change in text of TButtonedEdit inside thread. or how the same can be implemented using thread.

Thanks for Help.

Comment: Where does the data come from? I assume it takes some time to find the data you search for? Is the list view virtual (owner data)?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Application reads data from text file in Oncreate event. data is stored inside 'array of TArray<string>'. which is used for searching. Yes when there are many items for ex. 1000+ it takes time & UI gets stuck. I'm using TListView(Win32).

Comment: I am not at all convinced threading is your solution. If your list box is not virtual, then I think that *that* is your main problem. Make it virtual.

Comment: Have the main thread write the search text to a variable, and then signal the search thread. Use a lock to synchronise access to the variable.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I'm new to delphi. never used TlistView as virtual. I will definitely try it. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Praesoon: You might find [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074210/282848) illuminating.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That example is very concise. I will surely give it a try. Thankyou.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand i have tried implementing search process in a separate thread for peace of mind and failed to improve anything. you were right. slowest process is to update items in Tlistview. doing search in a separate thread will not help cause listview still need to get updated in main thread itself. I have tried using virtual Tlistview and it worked flawlessly. your example helped me a lot. TYSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't detect change of your TButtonedEdit directly from your worker thread.

What you can do is use your OnChange event to notify your worker thread that change was made.

Or if you are creating your worker thread in your OnChange event you can signal existing thread to terminate and not return any result and then start a new thread to perform search with new search parameters. Do note that your search procedure needs to be designed in a way to allow thread to regularly check Terminated property of your worker thread unless you won't be able to terminate it before search is finished.

Comment: till now i was trying the second approach. of terminating previous thread & creating new one for the changed text in Onchange event. but failed to implement checks for Terminated inside thread properly. i will try fixing it again.  about the first approach to notify worker thread in ochange event. can you provide some code for this. Thanks for the Answer.

Comment: Firs approach is for when you already have a thread with a built-in messaging system like some threads from [Omni Thread Library](http://www.omnithreadlibrary.com/). Making such system isn't trivial so making one by yourself won't be an easy task. Also it might not even be woth it. Depending on what your application does. Such systems are usually used in combination of thread pooling where you create limited number of threads and then feed them dynamically assign work to them. ...

Comment: ... The advantage of thread-pooling is that you avoid overhead of creating and freeing threads. But it does require additional code for allocating jobs to those threads. So unless your application is doing lots of computations all the time all that additional code might not make it worthwhile. I suspect that sticking to second approach might be enough for you.

Comment: Yes for now first approach too much for me. i will stick with second approach. Thanks for the Info.