# Delphi: Sort items in virtual TListView

Tags: listview, delphi, vcl, tlistview, virtuallistview

On a non-virtual `TListView` it is possible to sort items when clicking on a column,
by using the [`CustomSort`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/CustomSort_(Delphi)) function in the `OnColumnClick` event handler.

However when the Listview is virtual, this approach does not work.
The `CustomSortProc` callback is never called.

How to sort items of a virtual `TListView`?

Comment: In a virtual list view, the list view control doesn't contain any data. Instead, it simply asks you for the things to show at each instance of time. Typically, *you* have the data in some memory buffer (array, list, ...), and you then simply tell the control "Hey, I want to show N items." and then you give the control the appropriate strings each time it asks for an item. So if you want to sort your data, you only need to sort your own buffer (array, list, ...) and then tell the list view control to redraw itself (`TListView.Invalidate`).

Comment: [Here's an example I wrote not long ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074210/282848) It's not about *sorting* a virtual list view, but about *filtering*. However, if you really understand how to do filtering, you absolutely, definitely know how to do sorting.